# Non-System Disk Error" or "Disk Error" Appears on Black Screen

Tags: server, hp

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12. 04 server on my old 2002 HP 268900-999 desktop. I made a start up USB using the live disk creator in Ubuntu 13. 10. I set the computer to boot to USB first in the BIOS but when I boot I get a Non-System Disk Error" or "Disk Error" Appears on Black Screen. The USB drive is the only USB device connected to the machine (apart from a keyboard and a mouse) and it works on a different computer, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it works on another computer I'm going to assume your 2002 HP 268900-999 desktop doesn't work with it. Can you burn and boot from a dvd?

Comment: The computer cant read DVDs and I don't have any cds.

Comment: Is the USB the _only_ USB device connected to the machine? Also try using another tool to create the USB, there are sometimes differences. For example, try [`unetbootin`](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-linux-usb-from-linux/), [`multisystem`](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) or [`YUMI`](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). I've had cases where a USB created by tool A did not work on machine X but did on machine Y while a USB created with tool B worked on X and not on Y.